# How do I access this JSON data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{"0":
    {"id":"276","course":"92","name":"Tutorial - Compound Measures",
    "activitylink":"2490","available":"1331231400","deadline":"1331235000"},
 "1":
    "example@gmail.com","reference":"example@gmail.com"}
```

I am trying to access this in jQuery/Javascript but I unable to. This is my jQuery:

```
$('#lessonSelect').live('change', function()
{
    $.getJSON('?ajax=true&lid='+$('#lessonSelect').val(), function(data)
    {     
        var len = data.length;      
        var lessonDialog = "";//initialise
        var launchLessonDiv = '<a href="' + data.reference + '">Launch Lesson</a>';

        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++)
        {
            lessonDialog += '<p>' + data[i].name + '</p>'; //get lesson name
        }

        $('#lessonDialog').html(lessonDialog); //insert lesson name into dialog
        $('#launchLessonDiv').html(launchLessonDiv);

    });   
});
```

This is basically for a select list. Each time the user selects something, links and other stuff on the page change. The stuff works when the page is first loaded but when I start selecting stuff in the select list the lessonDialog comes up blank with nothing inside it.

Comment: can you change the json source format? ...if so that would simplify issue... structure is not consistent between #1 and #2

Comment: What do you mean and how would I go about doing that? I am not very good with JSON. In fact, yesterday was the first time I've ever used JSON!

Comment: would be a lot cleaner if it came out as a pure array `[{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"}]`..post code you are creating it with

Answer (score 2):

Convert the object with numeric keys to a true array:

```
$.getJSON('?ajax=true&lid='+$('#lessonSelect').val(), function(data) {   
    data = Array.prototype.slice.call(data);
```

Your current method fails, because `{ ... }` results in the creation of an object, *not* an array. The `length` property of the object is `undefined`, so the loop would never get started:

```
for (var i=0; i<undefined; i++) ; // <-- 0 < undefined is always false
```

Comment: @user1219572 Just in the same way. After converting the object to an array, `data` is a true array, and array properties & methods can be used.

Comment: I've tried alert(data) after data = Array.prototype.slice.call(data) but it alerts nothing :/

Comment: @user1219572 Then your server is not sending the data as stated in the question. Set up a stand-alone [demo](http://jsfiddle.net) if you need more help.